# jQuery add Click event to existing click event

Tags: jquery, loops, event-handling, click, each

My Question:

I trigger a click event one time for every checkbox, now i want to add in special case a function to this click event.

```
jQuery(document).on("init.checkbox", function(){
    jQuery('.checkbox').each(function($index){

        jQuery(this).click(function(){
                    bla bla
        });
    });
});
```

Now i want to add for same and more classes a click event that just fired one time.
If i do this :

```
jQuery(document).on("click.checkbox.label", function() {
    jQuery('.radio, .label_radio, .checkbox, .label').each(function () {
        jQuery(this).bind('click', function (event) {

            console.log('event fired');
            loadDetailHeight();
        });
    });

});
```

i got evey time i click a new event in so it stacks.

Example:

```
12:30 : event fired
12:31 : event fired
12:31 : event fired
12:32 : event fired
12:32 : event fired
12:32 : event fired
```

It stacks every time one more. How can i reach that the event just add one time?... :(

Thx 4 Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `stopPropagation`, it prevents further propagation of the event :

```
jQuery(this).bind('click', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('event fired');
    loadDetailHeight();
});
```

Comment: Thx i tried it, but it dont work.
And now it works perfekt ... sry for this question -.-